# How can I backup and encrypt with tar, split and openssl, all in one command?

Tags: bash, backup, tar, pipe, openssl

I often use `tar` to backup my stuff in 4 gigabyte chunks to a directory on a FAT32-formatted disk, as documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR#Archive_Splitting).

To get that done, I use the following command: `tar -cvpj /path/to/directory/ | split -d -b 4000m - "backup.tar.bz2."`.

I want to encrypt these `tar.bz2.*` files with `openssl aes-256-cbc`, if possible right after making a 4 GB chunk instead of after the whole backup job. I'd like to know the proper command to do that, and how to reconstitute the archive after creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
tar -cvpj /path/to/directory | openssl aes-256-cbc -kfile /path/to/enc.key | split -d -b 4000m - backup.tar.bz2.enc.
```

To extract:

```
cat backup.tar.bz2.enc.* | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -kfile /path/to/enc.key | tar xvjf -
```

EDIT: I noticed that split has --filter.

EDIT: Since cbc chains blocks, it makes it difficult to join.  I put the split after the encryption to make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. I adapted it to use gpg. To tar/gpg/split: `tar -cJvpf - inputdirectory/ | gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 | split -d -b 100m - outputfile.tar.xz.gpg.` and to decrypt: `cat outputfile.tar.xz.gpg.* | gpg -d | tar -xJvpf -`